# Looking for Jacobi elliptic functions in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I’m trying to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem involving elliptic functions, using pre-existing code, that requires symbolic arguments for these functions.

I found numerical routines for elliptic functions in Scipy and mpmath. I found reference to jcn and jdn in Sympy 2009, but could not import them from Sympy version 1.6.2.

Comment: I can't see them in SymPy either. They might not be implemented. It's hard to tell sometimes what name functions might be listed under in different libraries though. I suggest opening a GitHub issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Thanks for checking. I will open a GitHub issue. Does anyone have any work around ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is the issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24494

Comment: It's hard to suggest a workaround without knowing what you want from these functions beyond accepting symbolic arguments. (It's easy to make a function with any name that accepts symbolic arguments e.g. `jcn = Function('jcn')`.)